# Probability & Statistics: Random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem similar to the well-known "Coupon Collector Problem."

A box of a certain brand of cereal comes with a special toy. There are 10 different toys in all.  How many packs you will need to buy until you find the first toy already acquired in previous purchases?

Comment: Janni, see my answer. If you have a problem calculationg the remaining probabilities let me know.

Comment: The formulation "the first toy already acquired in previous purchases" is slightly odd. Do you mean "any toy previously found" or "the toy found in the pack which was bought first"?

Comment: Did "any toy previously found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Ioanni, the worst case is 11 boxes and the best case 2 (I see you have already mentioned that in the comments). Compute the probabilities of needing 2,3,4 until 11 boxes and take the expected value (your question should read "What is the expected number of packs you will need to buy....").

Therefore define the random variable $X$ that counts the number of packs that you will need. You have $$P(X=2)=\frac{1}{10}$$ The intuition is that the probability that $X=2$ is exactly the probability that the second pack will match the first pack. So, for the second pack you have only $1$ possibility out of $10$ (that is, to be equal the first pack). For the first pack you have no restrictions, it could have been any. Similarly$$P(X=3)=\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{10}=\frac{18}{100}$$ The intuition is that now the second pack has to be different than the first pack (so 9 out 10 will do) and the third pack should be equal to either the first or the second, thus 2 possibilities out of 10 for that. Similarly you can find all the other probabilities. You have that

1. $P(X=2)=\frac{1}{10}=0.1$
2. $P(X=3)=\frac{9\cdot2}{10^2}=0.18$
3. $P(X=4)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot3}{10^3}=0.216$
4. $P(X=5)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot4}{10^4}=0.2016$
5. $P(X=6)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5}{10^5}=0.1512$
6. $P(X=7)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot6}{10^6}=0.09072$
7. $P(X=8)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot7}{10^7}=0.042336$
8. $P(X=9)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot8}{10^8}=0.014515$
9. $P(X=10)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot9}{10^9}=0.003266$
10. $P(X=11)=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{10^9}=0.000363$

    Finally you should find that $$P(X=11)=\frac{9!}{10^9}$$ (Be careful that all probabilities should sum up to $1$). Then calculate the expected value of $X$ which is given by the formula $$E[X]=2\cdot P(X=2)+3\cdot P(X=3)+\ldots+10\cdot P(X=10)+11\cdot P(X=11)$$ This is the required $n$ when is equal to $$E[X]=4,66$$ (if my calculations are correct).

Comment: Stefanos first of all thank you for your response.I unerstood the logic but i think i have a problem to find the remaing probabilities..Help me please :)

Comment: Ok, Jianni, I will post it in another answer. I hope they are correct...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is not possible.

Suppose you get the toy of type $T_1$ in the $1^{st}$ box.
Then,

- The probability of getting the toy of type $T_1$ again in $2^{nd}$ box is $\frac{9}{10}\frac{1}{10}$
- The probability of getting the toy of type $T_1$ again in $3^{rd}$ box *(and failing in previous attempts)* is $\frac{9}{10}\frac{9}{10}\frac{1}{10} = {(\frac{9}{10}})^2\frac{1}{10}$
- The probability of getting the toy of type $T_1$ again in $4^{th}$ box  *(and failing in previous attempts)*  is ${(\frac{9}{10}})^3\frac{1}{10}$
- The probability of getting the toy of type $T_1$ again in $n^{th}$ box  *(and failing in previous attempts)* is ${(\frac{9}{10}})^{n-1}\frac{1}{10}$

If you succeed after picking $n$ boxes, then :
${(\frac{9}{10}})^{n-1}\frac{1}{10} = 1$

Just take $\log$ of both the sides and convince yourself that you get a non-realistic value of $n$.

Comment: The result is -20.So the result tha i want to calculate is |-20|=20 or i have done a mistake

Comment: You cannot buy -20 packets. The answer should have been 20 and there must not be any need to take absolute value. In such answers, the non-realistic values are discarded. Please post the solution and/or hint if you have.

Comment: 20 packets can not be the answer.We have 10 toys.Worst case scenario is 11 packets....

Comment: You have not mentioned the constraint that each of the 10 different toys will be distributed in 10 packets. So I assumed that each packet can have any toy. :) I have not read the Coupen Collector Problem and gave the solution based on tne 2nd and 3rd line of the problem.

Comment: Each packet has 1 type of toy . There are 10 different types of toys.How many packs you will need to buy until you find the first toy already acquired in previous purchases?  Think its better now. Can you give me a hand ?:)

Answer (score 0):

The probability of not drawing a duplicate before and drawing a duplicate in the $n^\text{th}$ box would be
$$
\underbrace{\left(1-\frac0{10}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{n-2}{10}\right)}_{n-1\text{ factors}}\frac{n-1}{10}
=\frac{10!(n-1)}{10^n(11-n)!}
$$
Thus, the expected box would be
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{11}n\frac{10!(n-1)}{10^n(11-n)!}=\frac{7281587}{1562500}=4.66021568
$$

---

**A Note on the Distribution**
$$
\frac{10!(n-1)}{10^n(11-n)!}
=\frac{10!}{10^{10}}\left(\frac{10^{11-n}}{(11-n)!}-\frac{10^{10-n}}{(10-n)!}\right)
$$
which shows that
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{11}\frac{10!(n-1)}{10^n(11-n)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{11}\frac{10!}{10^{10}}\left(\frac{10^{11-n}}{(11-n)!}-\frac{10^{10-n}}{(10-n)!}\right)\\
&=\frac{10!}{10^{10}}\left(\frac{10^{10}}{10!}-\frac{10^{-1}}{(-1)!}\right)\\[9pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Which verifies that the expected value of $1$ is $1$ (the distribution is a valid probability distribution).

Answer (score 0):

I see this a simple geometric distribution (Special case negative binomial distribution)

In the first cereal box, you will find a toy, let's call this $T_{1}$. $T_1$ is one random toy out of the 10 possible toy. Once the first toy is selected, the probability of getting the same toy again is $P(T_{1})=\dfrac{1}{10}
 $.

Let's call getting the event of getting the same toy again success. The probability of success in 0.1. Let X be the no. of trials/attempts before success.

The E(X), which is the expected value is the average number of trials before success is achieved. The formula for the expected value of a geometric distribution is $E(X)=\dfrac{(1-p)}{p}$ where $p$ is the probability of success.

In this case, $p=0.1$,
$$E(X)=\dfrac{0.9}{0.1}=9$$

So, on average it will take 9 attempts before success is achieved. Further distribution can be estimated using the Tschebycheff's inequality.

Answer open to criticism.

Comment: The probability of drawing a previously drawn toy in the first box is $0$. The probability of drawing a previously drawn toy in the second box is $\frac1{10}$. The probability of not drawing a previously drawn toy in the second box and drawing a previously drawn toy in the third box is $\frac9{10}\frac2{10}$. The probability of success is not the same for each box.

Comment: Oh yes, I see my mistake. Thank you for that